# PrimeFaces command button didn't invoke actionListener before redirecting

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

The env is PrimeFaces + Glassfish + Hibernate.

A 'Create' command button will redirect to a PurchaseOrder form page, the managed bean is session scoped,  PurchaseOrder has one-to-one relationship with Product. An auto-complete will select a Product to populate the bean.

My design is, it will create a new object before the redirecting .

There are two issues, first one, the button didn't invoke the actionListener, the second one is Product object is null, but actually it is created in the PostConstruct event.

```
<p:commandButton id="createButton" actionListener="purchaseOrderController.prepareCreate" value="#{bundle.Create}"  action="Form.xhtml?faces-redirect=true" />
```

Managed bean

```
@Named("purchaseOrderController")
@SessionScoped
public class PurchaseOrderController implements Serializable {   
    private PurchaseOrder selected;
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        selected = new PurchaseOrder();
        selected.setProduct(new Product());     
    }

     public PurchaseOrder prepareCreate() {
        System.out.println("prepareCreate"); //didn't get invoked
        selected = new PurchaseOrder();
        return selected;
    }
    //....
}
```

Product autocomplete

```
<p:autoComplete id="Product" value="#{purchaseOrderController.selected.product}" 
                                                    completeMethod="#{productController.completeProduct}" 
                                                    var="product" itemLabel="${product.name}" 
                                                    itemValue="#{product}" converter="productConverter" forceSelection="true" >                                       
                                        <p:ajax event="itemSelect" update=":PurchaseOrderForm" /> 
                                    </p:autoComplete>
```

error message

```
Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /purchaseOrder/Form.xhtml @49,128 value="#{purchaseOrderController.selected.product}": Target Unreachable, 'null' returned null
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.setValue(TagValueExpression.java:133)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.updateModel(UIInput.java:832)
    ... 51 more
Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Target Unreachable, 'null' returned null
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getTarget(AstValue.java:192)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.setValue(AstValue.java:226)
    at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.setValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:294)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.setValue(WeldValueExpression.java:64)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.setValue(TagValueExpression.java:131)
    ... 52 more
```

Comment: for more info see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909267/differences-between-action-and-actionlistener

Comment: You should already know that you should ask one question per Question. Please split. This way they can properly be closed as duplicates.

Comment: I did not even read up to the 'two issues' part.

Answer (score 0):

this is not a duplicate question. actually I forget to use EL expression in actionListener.

```
actionListener="purchaseOrderController.prepareCreate"
```

should be

```
actionListener="#{purchaseOrderController.prepareCreate}"
```